# How to generate HDF5/H5 file in Keras with existing Python project

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow.js

I am trying to get HDF5/H5 file from existing project in keras.

[this attention_ocr](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/attention_ocr/python) is related to OCR written in python. I would like to generate HDF5/H5 file so I can convert that with `tensorflowjs_converter`[[ref]](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html) and will use  in browser.

###### Reference:

- [How to import a TensorFlow SavedModel into TensorFlow.js](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter)
- [Importing a Keras model into TensorFlow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html)

I am looking for installing keras environment and generating HDF5/H5 file.

Answer (score 3):

Once your model is trained in keras, saving it as an HDF5 is simply one line:

```
my_model.save('my_filename.h5')
```

Comment: first thanks for your valuable response, i try to install every required thinks but somewhere something is missing. As i am new in ML i don't know where to execute `my_model.save('my_filename.h5')` this command. I try to execute it in console but it failed.

Comment: it is better if anyone know any youtube link video regarding to this `HDH5/F5` file generation with `Keras`......!

Comment: You should put that line in the python script you trained your model in (after model.fit).  This tutorial goes over some basics: https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/